# Software or website for validating and correcting for XHTML syntax

Tags: xhtml

I have some `jsp` pages and `html` pages.

I would like to format all of them so that all are conform to XHTML standard.

Is there any software or online website that provide the functionality of validating XHTML pages and if possible auto-correcting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of validators around but not necessarily autocorrecting.

`CSE HTML Validator` is one.  This will indicate errors in your code by line and make recommendations.

`HTML Tidy` will autocorrect.  I believe it does XHTML.  Do a backup of your files before using it as the result may not always be what you want.

W3 run an `online validator` http://validator.w3.org/.  This will show you your errors.

Answer (score 0):

http://validator.w3.org/ Try this website. This website validates the website according to w3c standards.